# Program just stops when trying to initiate a pattern for regex

Tags: android, regex, android-studio

I am trying to parse out all the toll information from a string that I have.  I tested this in eclipse and it works fine but when I implement it in the android IDE and run the code the debugger just stops on the declaration of the pattern i pointed out below.  So the program does not crash, there is no stack trace or exception thrown.  The other patterns work no problem but the toll pattern just does something really weird.

```
g="routes:[{routeName:Dulles Toll Rd W; SR-28 S,routeDurationInMinutes:18,routeLengthKM:21.474,routeLengthMiles:13.343320854,toll:true},{routeName:Frying Pan Rd; SR-28 S,routeDurationInMinutes:18,routeLengthKM:19.437,routeLengthMiles:12.077588127,toll:false}],startPoint:12801 Worldgate Drive, Herndon, VA 20170,endPoint:14069 Lotus Ln, Centreville, VA,startLatitude:38.95459763380265,startLongitude:-77.38901112241822,endLatitude:38.954550193428965,endLongitude:-77.38874605682294";
ArrayList parse = new ArrayList();
ArrayList route = new ArrayList();
ArrayList time = new ArrayList();
ArrayList toll= new ArrayList();
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("routeName?.+?routeLengthKM");
Matcher m = p.matcher(g);
Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("routeName?.+?routeDurationInMinutes");
Pattern p3 = Pattern.compile("routeDurationInMinutes?.+?routeLengthKM");
Pattern ptoll = Pattern.compile("toll?.+?}");  //<-- dies here
Matcher m3 = p3.matcher(g);
Matcher mtoll = ptoll.matcher(g);

while (m.find()) {
    parse.add(m.group());
}

while (m3.find()) {
    time.add(m3.group());
}

while (mtoll.find()) {
    toll.add(mtoll.group());
}
```

Comment: Just checking to make sure but have you tried putting a breakpoint on the line after `Pattern.compile("toll?.+?}");` to be absolutely sure it's stopping at that line?

Comment: no but i put a print statement that never got hit.  It just says that it is waiting for last debug command to finish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix your regular expression. I'm not sure why, but for some reason it doesn't like `"toll?.+?}"`. You need to change that line to this:

```
Pattern ptoll = Pattern.compile("toll?.+?\\}");
```

The change being `\\` which will escape the `}` and let `Pattern` know that it's a literal `}`.

Comment: yep that was it!  thank-you! I have no idea why it worked in eclipse but not android studio lol.

Comment: Yea, not sure either. Good luck with your project!